# Using two yaml files for configuration properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, configuration, yaml

We are using a spring boot application, where properties are loaded from  `application.yml` file instead of `application.properties`, located at `src/main/resources/` which looks like below:

```
config: 
  host: localhost:8080  
  server: 123
```

And they are being pulled in a `.java` file like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix="config")  
public class ConnectionImpl implements Connection{
  @Value("${config.host}")
  private Stringhost;
}
```

I am able to retrieve properties this way.
But we are trying to move the config properties from `application.yml` to a different `.yml` file which is located at a different location. (`src/main/resources/env-config`).
Now I am not able to retrieve properties same way, i.e, using `@Value` annotation. Is there any other annotation I need to add ?

Comment: Do you need to load both yaml properties at the same time or at different environments - eg. dev / test / prod environments? Also, do you need the Configurations properties or could you live with Properties source? eg. @PropertySource("classpath:${some.file.name}.yaml") - this way you can use  a OS env variable SOME_FILE_NAME or a param like -Dsome.file.name= in the java command line startup call.

Comment: We need both at the same time. We need Configuration properties.

Comment: In this case what I'd is a mix of multiple properties files + environments vars. For instance, I'd have a "jms.<environment>.yaml" and a "db.<environment>.yaml" and even a "utils.<environment>.yaml". Each of these files will have a pojo annotated with @PropertySource("classpath:/com/${my.path:default/path}/db.${env:local}.properties") - you can override this with -Dmy.path=path/to/yaml/files and -Denv=dev in command line - so if you pack your yaml in your jars, it would find the props there, but if you needed to change this to a yaml file on the filesystem, you can also override it there too.

Comment: Sorry, I answered with PropertiesSource, but you should also be able use ConfigurationProperties instead too, with the same model, which spring boot construct for you atuomatically.

Answer (score 10):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> `SpringApplication` will load properties from `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) files in the following locations and add them to the Spring `Environment`:
>
> 1. A `/config` subdirectory of the current directory.
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath `/config` package
> 4. The class path root
>
> If you don’t like `application.properties` as the configuration file name you can switch to another by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. **You can also refer to an explicit location using the `spring.config.location` environment property (comma-separated list of directory locations, or file paths)**.
>
> The default search path `classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/` is always used, irrespective of the value of `spring.config.location`. This search path is ordered from lowest to highest precedence (`file:config/` wins). If you do specify your own locations, they take precedence over all of the default locations and use the same lowest to highest precedence ordering. In that way you can set up default values for your application in `application.properties` (or whatever other basename you choose with `spring.config.name`) and override it at runtime with a different file, keeping the defaults.

You need to supply a command line argument that tells `SpringApplication` where specifically to look. If everything in `resources/` is added to the classpath root, then your command line would look like:

`java -jar myproject.jar --Dspring.config.location=classpath:/env-config/service-config.yml`

If you have a general `application.yml` under `resources/`, the properties in there will still be loaded but will take a lower precedence to the properties file specified on the command line.

Answer (score 9):

Your question doesn't really say what you intend to do, but if you want to have a different configuration for different environments (e.g. `development`, `test`, `production`), there is a simple solution for that.

Place your config files in a file hierarchy like this inside your project:

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      application.yml
      application-development.yml
      application-test.yml
      application-production.yml
```

When you now start your application with

```
java -jar mySpringApplication.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=development
```

the configuration from `application.yml` will be taken as a "base layer", overridden by the configuration in `application-development.yml`. By this, you can have "default" settings for all environments in `application.yml` and environment-specific configuration in the `application-ENV.yml` files. The same works for `test` and `production`.

Answer (score 4):

No.

You'll be in a much better position if you avoid hard-coding file path like that within your code base. `@ConfigurationProperties` used to have a `locations` attribute but it's deprecated and already removed in 1.5.

In Spring Boot, you configure the `Environment` which is a single source of truth for your configuration. Rather than having settings buried in code, you should configure Spring Boot to read the files that you want. [Read the documentation for `spring.config.location`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files). If you want to do this in a more transparent manner, perhaps [`EnvironmentPostProcessor` is what you need](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)

Comment: Hi Stephanie, thanks for the answer. Not sure what you meant about using spring.config.location. In my application.yml, I gave the location for another yaml I am using by using the   config:
    location: classpath:/env-config/service-config.yml. But still its not picking the properties from here.

Comment: Reading the doc should help. You can't specify that property there, it must be set when the app starts. See the link I gave for more details.